# Understanding tf.gather_nd in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tensor "a" of shape [72, 3, 65] and indices "b" from `tf.top_k` with shape [72, 3]. What I am trying to do is:

```
c = tf.gather_nd(a, b)
```

Where `c` has shape [72] but I want it to have shape [72, 3, 65]. How do I do this?

Edit:

I think I found a round-about way to do it using tf.gather, but how could I do this using gather_nd instead to simplify things, or am I misunderstanding its purpose?

```
a = tf.reshape(a, [dim_1_size*dim_2_size, -1])
b = tf.reshape(b, [-1])

c = tf.gather(a, b)
c = tf.reshape(c, old_a_shape)
```